# Select 2 Column of 2 Table

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 tables:

- `Staff`: (ID, NAME)
- `Salary`: (ID, VALUE)

My problem is:

1. How could I write in query syntax and method syntax in controller and return to the `View()`, like this in SQL query:

   ```
    select a.NAME, b.VALUE 
    from Staff a, Salary b 
    where a.ID = b.ID
   ```
2. How could I declare in view like:

   ```
    @model IEnumerable<Project.Model.xxxx>
   ```

This is the way I do with one table in `IndexController`:

```
LinQDataContext data = new LinQDataContext();

public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
     var staffWithTheirSalary = data.Staff
                                    .Select(a => a)
                                    .Where(a => a.ID == id);
}
```

Index view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Project.Model.Staff>

@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    @item.Name
}
```

Comment: Create viewmodel and put all your data which you want to pass in view in that viewmodel. Use that viewmodel in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your view model to be `IEnumerable<StaffSalaryViewModel>` where `StaffSalaryViewModel` is:

```
public class StaffSalaryViewModel
{
    public int StaffId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Salary { get; set; } // Not sure of the type
}
```

Then to extract the list:

Using Linq method syntax:

```
var result = data.Staff
   .Join(data.Salary,
      staff => staff.ID,
      salary => salary.ID,
      (staff, salary) => new StaffSalaryViewModel { 
         StaffId = staff.ID, 
         Name = staff.NAME, 
         Salary = salary.VALUE 
      });
```

Using Linq query syntax:

```
var result = from staff in data.Staff 
         join salary in data.Salary on staff.ID equals salary.ID
         select new StaffSalaryViewModel { 
            StaffId = staff.ID, 
            Name = staff.NAME, 
            Salary = salary.VALUE 
         };
```

**UPDATE**

It looks like the `VALUE` field in your `Salary` table allows null values. If so just make the corresponding property in your view model nullable, like so (provided it is a `decimal` type):

```
public class StaffSalaryViewModel
{
    public int StaffId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal? Salary { get; set; } // Nullable/optional decimal
}
```

Or if you want to set `StaffSalaryViewModel.Salary` to 0 If `VALUE` is null, change your query to have:

```
 Salary = salary.VALUE ?? 0
```

Comment: i got a message like property in StaffSalaryViewModel  is null :(

Comment: @AK109, it looks like your `Salary` table allows null for `VALUE` field. So just make `StaffSalaryViewModel.Salary` nullable. As I said, I do not know the type of that field as it was not indicated in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Because tables are being joined, I prefer using the `query syntax`. The controller would use the LinQDataContext to get at the data, but when creating the C# Object I would recommend creating a Class that is only used for displaying the data (in the example its called `MySalaryModel`).

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    IEnumerable<Project.Model.MySalaryModel> staffWithTheirSalary = from staff in data.Staff
            join salary in data.Salary on staff.Id equals salary.Id
            select new Project.Model.MySalaryModel 
            {
                Id = staff.Id,
                Name = staff.Name,
                Salary = salary.Value,
            };

    return View(staffWithTheirSalary);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use ViewModel,
you can create Viewmodel Folder in project and Create class into like this.

```
 public class StaffSalaryViewModel
    {
     public int StaffId { get; set; }
     public int SalaryeId { get; set; }
     public string StaffName { get; set; }
     public string SlaaryName { get; set; }

    }
```

in action :

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
  StaffSalaryViewModel staffWithTheirSalary = (from itemStaff in data.Staff join     itemSalary in data.Salary in itemStaff.id equal itemSalary.id where itemSalary.id=id select new StaffSalaryViewModel {Salaryname=itemSalary.Name,StaffName=itemStaff.Name,SalaryId=itemSalary.Id,itemStaff.Id}).ToList();
}
```

in View

```
@model IEnumerable<Project.ViewModel.StaffSalaryViewModel>

@foreach(var item in Model)
{
  @item.SalaryName
}
```